# Meaning of 運命とはわからない

Tags: particle-と, reading-comprehension

> まる子のタコ風船は、七夕飾りのとがった部分にさわってしまい、ものすごい音ではぜてしまったのだ**から運命とはわからない**。
>   Maruko's octopus balloon ended up touching a sharp part of a Tanabata decoration and burst with a tremendous sound, so ????

I'm confused about 運命とはわからない. I thought とは was used when giving a definition. So this would be "..so Maruko doesn't understand (the definition/meaning of) fate".

I think this translation must be wrong because I don't see how it can be a consequence (から) of the events described.

Comment: I think here it's basically "you never know what fate will bring".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here わからない doesn't mean "someone is not able to understand" but works as if an adjective that means "not understandable". So the translation would be like,

> 運命とはわからない
> *(What) the fate (is) is inexplicable*

This usage is but an extension of perhaps more familiar wordings as follows:

> 大切なことは目に見えない *what is essential is invisible to the eye*
>
> 経済に与える影響は無視できない *the impact to economy is considerable (not negligible)*

Also, `[story] のだから [comment]` is an idiomatic(?) construction that effectively expresses the nuance of "*[story]*, which explains how *[comment]*" or "considering *[story]*, it is indeed *[comment]*".

Answer (score 3):

goo国語辞書 says:

> #### [とは](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/159809/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF/)
>
> 2. 定義・**命題**などの主題であることを示す。…というものは。「友情とは、かけがえのないものだ」

So とは is not limited to giving a definition, but it can also be used to present a general expected feature of something. ("～ is always ～", "～ is supposed to ～")

Some examples from BCCWJ:

> - 結婚とはするものだし、両親や親戚も彼女に結婚しろと言っている。
>     (Marriage is something you (are expected to) do)
> - 女とは恐ろしいものだ。天性のうそつきの化けものだ、と平太郎は痛嘆した。
>     (Women are horrible beings)
> - おぬしもまた、朝鮮へ明へ呂宋へ、その彼方の国々へ兵を挙げるだろう。力とはそういうものだからだ。
>     (That's what power is (supposed to mean))

Answer (score 1):

> ～*だ*から

because ～

(Semantically speaking, saying 運命とはわからない when you merely bursting a balloon a bit overblown, it seems to me.)

> 運命とはわからない

運命 is the subject of 分からない and the whole sentence. The と before the は denotes something like というもの.

Comment: His problem seems to be how 運命とはわからない and the previous sentence are related.

Comment: Don't forget that you can also answer in Japanese if you feel more comfortable using Japanese.