# What does "とは" mean in these sentences?

Tags: meaning, particles

I can't understand why "とは" is being used in the following sentences:

> 1)...質問があります。その質問**とは**、「なぜ、皆マスクをしているの？」...
>
> 2) 花粉症**とは**、植物の花粉によって起こるアレルギーです。

Comment: `その質問とは、「なぜ、皆マスクをしているの？」` -- Is this the whole sentence? It's followed by です or something, no?

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/47416/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38579/9831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the とは particles are used to mark a definition or explanation of something. The structure is `<thing you are going to explain/define>　とは　<description>`

Let's take a look at those two sentences. I've bolded the English words that are translated from とは

So in the first sentence the speaker says,

> I have a question. That question **is** "why is everyone wearing a mask?".

the とは marks that the speaker is about the explain/define what his/her question is.

The second sentence is the same structure. The sentence is explaining what 花粉症 (or hay fever) is.

> Hay fever **(is/can be defined as/is explained as)** the allergy to plant polen.

[This site](http://learnjapanesedaily.com/japanese-grammar-dictionary/japanese-grammar-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF-toha.html) does a good job of explaining the basic uses of とは if you want to learn a little more.

Comment: その "This site" ってとこのリンク、"Page not found" ってなるんですが。

Comment: そのサイト、（「とは」のページだけでなく、他のページでも、）例文が、かなり間違っていたり不自然だったりしてますので、ちょっと気を付けて使ってください・・・　例えば、そのページだけでも：「JKとは女子高校生の省略**の刑**です」「希少動物とは**固体**の数**量**が少ない動物**ものだ** 」「彼が私にさよならと**言うとは**もう会えなく**なるでしょうか** 」「5歳の**子共は**漢字だらけの本が読める**とは** ・・・」（いくつか漢字も間違ってます・・・）